# Проблема создания конструктора хэш-таблицы C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, sfinae

Я делаю класс хэш-таблицы `xhash<_Traits>`, где класс `_Traits` - это структура, содержащая информацию о том, какие типы у ключа, значений, аллокатора, компаратора и является ли таблица мультитаблицей (т.е. можно ли класть несколько значений с одинаковым ключём). По сути делаю аналог `xhash` из `std`.

Немного информации о таблице, чтобы я смог полностью описать проблему:

- От этой таблицы можно наследоваться с определённым классом `_Traits`, тем самым создавая контейнеры, использующие хэш-таблицу (по типу `unordered_set`, `unordered_multiset`, `unordered_map` и т.д.)
- В моей таблице есть также итераторы, которые по сути являются итераторами списка, в котором хранятся все ключи со значениями.
- Помимо списка, в таблице хранится вектор итераторов на элементы, по которому я получаю доступ к цепочкам.

И специально для случая, если хэш-таблица используется для множества, где ключ и значение - один и тот же тип, и в котором нельзя менять хранящиеся там объекты пользователю через итераторы (иначе структура поломается) я написал следующее:

```
using iterator = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<key_type, value_type>, 
                 typename _Mylist::const_iterator, typename _Mylist::iterator>;
```

т.е. если ключ и значение имеют один и тот же тип, то вместо итератора используется константный итератор.

А теперь сама проблема: в конструкторе по умолчанию мне приходится писать такую конструкцию:

```
xhash() : _List(), _Vec(_List.end()) {}
```

т.к. у итераторов нет конструктора по умолчанию. Но что если у меня итераторы константные? Тогда мне нужно передавать не `end()`, а `cend()`. Я пытался решить эту проблему с помощью `std::enable_if_t`:

```
template<class = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same_v<iterator, const_iterator> > >
xhash() : _List(), _Vec(default_size, _List.cend()) {}
template<class = std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same_v<iterator, const_iterator> > >
xhash() : _List(), _Vec(default_size, _List.end()) {}
```

Но это решение не подходит, т.к. у меня получается два конструктора одинакового приоритета. Как тогда эту проблему решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл здесь два выхода:

1. **Добавить конструктор по умолчанию итераторам.** Оказывается в STL итераторы имеют конструкторы по умолчанию и они, видимо, создают итератор с `nullptr`. Тогда если у итератора есть конструктор по умолчанию, то можно написать так:

```
xhash() : _List(), _Vec(default_size, iterator()) {}
```

2. **Сконструировать вектор по умолчанию, а потом сделать resize.** На это решение навёл меня @AR Hovsepyan. Когда вектор создаётся, он не создаёт никаких объектов, его массив - это nullptr, поэтому ошибки не возникнет. А потом сделать `resize` с заполнением объектом:

```
xhash() : _List(), _Vec() {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<key_type, value_type>)
        _Vec.resize(default_size, _List.cend());
    else _Vec.resize(default_size, _List.end());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял, можно присваивать в теле конструктора (да, иногда нужно использовать и его тело(:).

```
xhash() 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<key_type, value_type>)
    {
        _Vec = _List.cend();
    }
    else
        _Vec = _List.end();
}
```

Comment: Интересно, как это я буду присваивать итератор вектору

Comment: а вы предлагаете мне вникать в суть  ваших объектов? Но ведь вам нужно только знать способ.. Ну подставляйте нужный  объект

Comment: Да как обычный `std::vector` работает. Но хотя на самом деле, ваше предложение натолкнуло меня на возможное решение: использовать `resize()` в аргументы которого я передам элемент, которым можно заполнить.